# Coding Challenge - Employee Scheduling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, coldfusion

So, I am trying to figure out the most efficient way of auto-calculating days off for employees and insure maximum coverage.  I am using ColdFusion and Javascript on MySQL, but can easily add jQuery or switch to PHP if that is a better platform to work with.

On to the requirements.  This is for a company that has 50 employees, works 7 days a week, and has 2 - 10 hour shifts starting at 0600 and 1200 (25 employees per shift).  Each employee works 4 days then has 3 days off per 7 day week (Sun to Sat).  Every week their days off should progress - meaning, they won't have the same days off each week.  The employees stay on their shift for the year luckily.

The problem currently is inconsistent shift coverage.  Currently, Monday has lots of employees then Thursday is barely staffed due to how they rotate days off.  I am wanting to figure out the best way to automatically compute the best coverage.

Any ideas on how best to proceed?

Edit:  Ouch!  So I guess code is what you want to see and not theoretical math.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be basic math to figure this out, and once you've got the math right, you write the code ?

Comment: Well, I agree.  I got stuck with my loops inside of a loop and then my results were poor.  That's when I realized I wasn't doing the math right.  I know I can code it, but I am struggling to get the right math.  That's why I wanted to post and see what other peoples thoughts were and how they would construct the math loop for coverage.  Ideally, I will be able to alter the variables and the algorithm will auto adjust for the best coverage of their factory shifts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familiar with ColdFusion, and even if I was, this problem is sufficiently complex to make it infeasible for me to bash out some functioning code. But if you'll excuse that, I have some conceptual ideas for you (using JS to explain).

Start with giving every employee 4 days

```
var jim = 4;
var bob = 4;
var tom = 4;
```

Then sort the shifts by the least potentially schedulable employees (I assume this is in your DB, or if not, it is not too hard to calculate).

```
var thursday = 2;
var monday = 3;
```

Determine which employees are available.

```
var thEmployee = ['jim', 'tom'];
var monEmployee = ['jim', 'bob', 'tom'];
```

Once you have all this information, schedule the employee with the least available time into the shifts in ascending order of potentially available employees.

```
shifts.foreach(function(){
  var smallest = 'monday';
  days.foreach(function(){
    var current = //dammit, I forget how to specify this in JS, use your imagination, this is just an idea anyway
    if (current  < smallest) {
      //these vars are placeholders for the actual function that returns the count of the potential employees for the day
      smallest = current
    }
  });
});
```

That's the function for finding the shift with the least amount of potential employees. You do something similer to find the employee with the least amount of days remaining (currently all at 4, so it would grab Jim). And you schedule him. Then for monday, Jim would be the least available person, and it would grab him again. But if say tuesday came between them, and Jim is not available for tuesday, it would grab Bob, then both Bob and Jim are at 3 when it schedules monday.

Essentially what happens is the program says, "This person might not be able to be scheduled later, let's schedule them now instead of someone else who *can* take that later slot". Obviously this is very rudimentary, and the algorithm will need some tweaking to avoid dead-ending itself, but maybe this will give you an idea that will help you solve the problem.

Comment: Hey!  This is actually a good starting point to work from.  I was thinking of it in a different manner, i.e. starting with assigning employees first and then figuring out what they had left.  I think that if I work from their total days available down to 0, this will be a better format.